# Why not accessible methods and properties in Singleton instance

Tags: c#, .net, singleton

Work on Asp.net MVC5 application .Have one Class named **ContainerAdapter**. In my application I need to create this class instance **several** times.

So I decided to create single instance process like: **Singleton**.My syntax is bellow,face problem to get access properties and methods of class ContainerAdapter from the singleton instance;

**Adapter class**

```
public class ContainerAdapter
        {
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public void HelloWorld()
            {
                //
            }


            public string GetHelloWorld()
            {
                return "";
                //
            }
        }
```

**Singleton**

```
public class Singleton
    {
        private static Singleton instance = null;
        private Singleton()
        {
            ContainerAdapter apapter = new ContainerAdapter();            

        }
        // Lock synchronization object
        private static object syncLock = new object();

        public static Singleton Instance
        {
            get
            {

                lock (syncLock)
                {
                    if (Singleton.instance == null)
                        Singleton.instance = new Singleton();

                    return Singleton.instance;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

From Singleton instance want to access methods HelloWorld() and GetHelloWorld()

Comment: What problem do you face? Could you show how are you accessing and errors / exceptions you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use some sort of IoC-container for this, and not implement your singletons by hand.

But if you really want to implement it by hand, and use locks for synchronization, you would end up with something like the code below. Your singleton instance is a ContainerAdapter, so I just merged your two classes into one. You could write some generic Singleton class, but then again: IoC-containers have this kind of functionality built in.

```
public class ContainerAdapter
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public void HelloWorld()
        {
            //
        }


        private string GetHelloWorld()
        {
            return "";
            //
        }

    private static ContainerAdapter instance = null;

    // Lock synchronization object
    private static object syncLock = new object();

    public static ContainerAdapter Instance
    {
        get
        {

            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (ContainerAdapter.instance == null)
                    ContainerAdapter.instance = new ContainerAdapter();

                return ContainerAdapter.instance;
            }
        }
    }

}
```